# Join queries from two different databases on the different server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Can i use mySql and SQL Server DB combine, I have a stored procedure in sql server DB and i like to add another table to that procedure but that table is in mySql DB on a different server, is there some way to use two different DBs like this.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: imo not by a direct query - you have to use a server side programming language to combine the two databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a Linked Server in MSSQL, pointing to your MySQL server. In order to do that, you can follow the tutorial [here](http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/07/22/link-mysql-to-ms-sql-server2008/).